# What are some of the most popular ways to make Ajax call with JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I used to use ASP.NET update panel control to do Ajax.  I've heard that using JQuery would be a better way to make Ajax call, so I am wondering what are some of the most popular ways to make Ajax call with JQuery?  Example(s) or links to tutorials would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/ or http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely the best page / website to look at.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

or if you want

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp

```
$.ajax({
    url : "page.asp",
    data : {
        "param1" : 1,
        "param2" : "Hello World" //you can access these with the server's request object
    },
    type : "GET", //or post
    cache : true, //use your cache? (only applies to certain types)
    dataType : "json", //what kind of data are you expecting? (or Intelligent guess)
    success : function(message) { //message depends on dataType
        console.log(message);
    },
    error : function() {
        console.log(arguments);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways depending on your needs, but a common one is

```
$.get('/yoururl',{inputParam:someVal},function(data){
  //do whatever with the returned data

});
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is using web methods:
[jQuery AJAX call to an ASP.NET WebMethod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770679/jquery-ajax-call-to-an-asp-net-webmethod)

http://deebujacob.blogspot.ca/2012/01/aspnet-ajax-web-method-call-using.html

For example in your aspx.cs:

```
    [WebMethod()]
    public static string GetData(int userid)
    {
        /*You can do database operations here if required*/
        return "my userid is" + userid.ToString();
    }
```

in your aspx:

```
    function asyncServerCall(userid) {
        jQuery.ajax({
     url: 'WebForm1.aspx/GetData',
     type: "POST",
     data: "{'userid':" + userid + "}",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (data) {
         alert(data.d);
     }

        });
    }
```