# How to call c# class method from jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a C# class Data, stored in Data.cs, and there I have a simple method PrintName:

```
    void PrintName(string name)
    {
        Label lblName = new Label();
        lblName.Text = name;
        cph.Controls.Add(lblName);
    }
```

where cph is a ContentPlaceHolder of the asp.net page, where an instance of Data is created. And I need to pass some data from jQuery client side to C#, and I am trying this code:

```
function Print() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Data.cs/Data.PrintName",
    data: '{name: "Steven" }',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function () {
        jAlert('Success', 'Alert Dialog');
    },
    failure: function () {
        jAlert('Failure', 'Alert Dialog');
    }
});
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  Print();
}
```

The problem is that I am trying to call not the asp.net page itself, but a C# class, those instance has access to the page through cph variable. Is it possible to solve this somehow and pass data to the needed instance of the class?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14046879/993547.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the method PrintName with WebMethod Attribute. Change your Print() Ajax Method's Url to ".aspx/PrintName"