# Accessing PageMethod from aspx page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a webforms application and need to make an jquery ajax call to a PageMethod (i.e. WebMethod) in code behind from my aspx page. So far it does not work for me. Is this possible?
Here is my code:

```
    $(function()
    {
        setInterval(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/ClientBillingBillDetails.aspx/MyPageMethod",
                data: {someData: '<%= TheData %>'},
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(result) {

                }
            });
        }, 10000);
    });

    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string MyPageMethod(int someData)
    {
        return "";
    }
```

Is something wrong with my URL or something else?

Thanks

Comment: There are a number of articles out there.  Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770679/jquery-ajax-call-to-an-asp-net-webmethod), [this](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928533/calling-a-webmethod-with-jquery-in-asp-net-webforms)

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Describe exactly  the behavior you're seeing and what you expect to see. Include relevant information from debugging and examining the console and network tabs in your browser.

Comment: Sorry, "does not work" means the method is not called.

Comment: Check [this answer about how to make and call a Page method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30082988/function-not-defined-error-while-using-asp-net-ajax/30083658#30083658), or for more detail check the topic in [Stack Overflow Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/asp.net/1411/page-methods)

Comment: You still have not included enough information in your question. What method is not called? Have you checked the steps leading up to that message? Watched network traffic to see if an HTTP request is sent? Is your JavaScript AJAX call even reached? What happens if you add an error handler to your AJAX call?

Comment: The javascript ajax call is reached, and the error returned is "The resource cannot be found".

Comment: In your browser's network tools, is the request going to the correct URL? You're using a site relative path instead of application root relative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
$(function () {
            setInterval(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/ClientBillingBillDetails.aspx/MyPageMethod",
                    data: "{ 'someData': '<%= TheData %>' }",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {

                }
            });
        }, 10000);
        });
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you are suggesting to replace "GET" with "POST"? If yes, it did not help :(

Comment: you also make changes in **data** with double quoute for send data in json format.

Comment: I tried it. I get an error now: Invalid JSON primitive: someData.

When I debug, the data looks like this: data: {'someData': '1420715'}

Comment: have u try this **"{'someData': '1420715'}"** instead of {'someData': '1420715'} means surround double quote.

Answer (score 0):

Use type as post and make sure if you have ajax.jquery library reference added in solution.

Also i think you can remove '/' in specifying method..
Just use "ClientBillingBillDetails.aspx/MyPageMethod".

Else you can use simple pageMethods using scriptmanager