# How to update data in SQL for an html table row using Input Button, in JS or C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-4.5

I have a datatable in C# and I am converting it to html table like below.

```
public static string ConvertDataTableToHTML(DataTable dt)
{
        StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
        html.Append("<table id='example' class='table table-striped table-bordered' cellspacing ='0' width ='100%' font size='8' aria-hidden='true'>");

       //add header row
        html.Append("<thead>");
        html.Append("<tr>");
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            html.Append("<td>" + dt.Columns[i].ColumnName + "</td>");
        html.Append("<td>" + "Action" + "</td>");
        html.Append("</tr>");
        html.Append("</thead>");

        //add rows
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            html.Append("<tr>");
            for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
                html.Append("<td>" + dt.Rows[i][j].ToString() + "</td>");
            html.Append("<td><input type=\"button\" value=\"Delete\" onclick=\"deleteRow(this)\"/></td>");
            html.Append("</tr>");
        }

        html.Append("</table>");

        return html.ToString();
}
```

This is showing a table in my aspx page like below:

```
Name City Quantity  Action
A     X      5      Delete
B     Y     10      Delete
C     Z     15      Delete
```

When I click "Delete" button for a row, the function below works and the row is gone from the result table.

```
<script>
    function deleteRow(btn)
     {
        var row = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
        row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
     }
</script>
```

What I want is that, in addition to the current process, I need to run a SQL query to update IsRemoved flag for this data in my SQL Server 2014 table.

The query I need to run: `Update MyTable set IsRemoved=1 where Name='A' and City='X'`

I could not manage to run it in JavaScript function, and could not find a way to execute another function in C# after the JS function. OnClientClick is not working since it is not an asp:Button, and when I try to use asp:Button instead of input element, it does not show it on the screen.

How can I change data in DB here for such an example? Please note that I am trying not to use a GridView. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: By using Ajax, how can I send paramaters from my ajax call to c#:

I am trying:

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'mypage.aspx/DeleteRowFromDB',
     data: JSON.stringify({ name: **<nameshouldcomehere>**, city:**<cityshouldcomehere>** }),
     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     dataType: 'json',
      success: function (msg) {
           var row = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
           row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
      }
});
```

I can't find how to set name and city dynamically based on the row clicked the delete button, any tips?

Comment: call an `ajax` function which will call a `WebMethod` on your`.cs` page which will mark the row as IsRemoved in the DB and then on the success of the `ajax` remove the row from the `html`.

Comment: You can use `ajax` to post the `name` and the `city` values of the row to your server and have it call a stored procedure to mark that item as `IsRemoved`. Resource for how to use `ajax` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX)

Comment: A simple example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770679/jquery-ajax-call-to-an-asp-net-webmethod. Inside the webmethod you will execute the update query/stored procedure. And your button will call the ajax method with proper payload which will be used as your webmethod parameter. Heres another one https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx

Comment: Thanks all for the comments, I am working on setting an Ajax call to my page, I'll update you with the result.

Comment: @vikscool can u see the edit please?

Comment: @RyanWilson can u see the edit please?

Comment: @ErayBalkanli **1st** To get the `Name` and `City`, take your code`var row = btn.parentNode.parentNode;` out of the ajax call. So its row values can be accessed easily. **2nd** you can access the `td` values from the `row` variable created like: `var cells = row.getElementsByTagName("td");` and then it will return you an array of whose `innerText` property you can use to get their value like:`var name = cells[0].innerText; var city=cells[1].innerText;`

Comment: @vikscool thanks, it is working. You saved my day. If you add an answer to this question I'll upvote it and select as correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `.cs` page create a `WebMethod` which will mark the `Database` entry as `IsRemoved=1` as:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string DeleteRowFromDB(string name,string city)
{
   var status = "0";
   //Your code to mark `IsRemoved=1` for the selected entry goes here and set the `status` variable as status="1" if the DB command successed.
   return status;
}
```

And then create a function with an `ajax` call to invoke the created `WebMethod` and remove the row from `HTML` if the `status` is true as:

```
function deleteRow(btn)
{
   var row = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
   var cells = row.getElementsByTagName("td");
   var reqData = JSON.stringify({ name: cells[0].innerText, city:city=cells[1].innerText });
   //now make a call to the `WebMethod` via `ajax`.
   $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'mypage.aspx/DeleteRowFromDB',
    contenttype: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: reqData,
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function (response) {        
       if(response === "1") {
          row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
       }
       else
       {
         //do other stuff
       }
    },
    error: function (error) {
        //handle the error
    }
});

}
```

**Note**: if the `response` variable in the `ajax` success function doesn't have the desired value try to look for its `response.d` property value.